# How to add URL to a given stylus plugin style?

Tags: firefox, stylus

I use [stylus plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) in Firefox. I have a local Gitlab server, where I want to use a [dark theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/164877/dark-gitlab). The stylus plugin cannot find out, that my local Gitlab server is a Gitlab, because it is just an URL like: `192.168.1.2`, so stylus wont show it in dark. There are many assigned URLs to Dark-GitLab theme under Stylus -> Manage, but I cannot add my URL to it.

How can I add URL to a given stylus plugin style URL list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to Stylus -> Manage
2. Click on the given theme, you will see block of source codes.
3. There is an `Applies to` section under each code block. Click **+** on the right. (not to the Add button at the bottom).
4. Type your URL (`192.168.1.2`) and Save.